# How to store class in an array

Tags: swift

I want to check if an object belongs to some type. To do this, I can check a single type with `is`.

```
if cell is UITableViewCell{
    // do something
}
```

However, I'm working with various types. So, I want to create an array to store types of classes.

```
let types = [ ATableViewCell, BTableViewCell, CTableViewCell]
```

and then iterate on the array and check

```
for type in types{
    if cell is type{
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

The question is how to store a type of type to an array. Does Swift 2 allow me to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution. Here's the solution regarding [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html).

```
let types = [ ATableViewCell.self, BTableViewCell.self, CTableViewCell.self]
for type in types{
    if cell.dynamicType === type{
        // do something
    }
}
```